# can enterprise apps requiring HTML5's new feature(s) support non-HTML5 browsers?

Tags: apache-flex, html

My question is for programmers planning to develop future enterprise web apps in HTML5 that today can only be implemented in Flex/AS3: are you intending these apps to only run on HTML5 browsers?

I'm just trying to understand how once HTML5 enters the picture, the current concerns about browser incompatibility and other issues go away? Wouldn't HTML5 simply add another set of browsers to the large list of current browsers that the application must target?

That is, assuming the enterprise web app requires one of these new HTML5 features (e.g. playing audio and/or video, integrating SVG or vector graphics, etc.). If such a feature isn't critical then graceful degradation may be acceptable and then my question is moot.

But for those apps that require one of these new HTML5 features, are you planning to support older browsers, or expecting it's acceptable to restrict to HTML5 browsers because the enterprise in question has made one of them their new corporate standard (or other scenario, etc.)?

Comment: You can either ignore non standard compliant browsers or emulate features on legacy platforms. All modern browsers support 80% of "HTML5". The rest can be polyfilled.

Comment: How to polyfill embedding video without using a plug-in? Is this an example of crash-and-burn?

Comment: Flash makes a good polyfill, failing that, you crash and burn. I mean if you really wanted to you could try a Java/SL polyfill, but that seems like _far_ too much effort for _tiny_ gain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enterprise apps are no different then anything else.

You use the standard [polyfilling technique](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) and crash and burn on legacy platforms.

Generally modern browser support the sensible subset of HTML5 and any bugs can be polyfilled.